# SQL Query with Group By statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this 4 table:

Managers, Sales, SaleDetails, Products:

- **Managers**: ID, Name
- **Sales**: ID, ManagerID, SaleNO, SaleDate
- **SaleDetails**: ID, SaleID, ProductID, Quantity
- **Products**: ID, Name, Price

I want to retrive for each manager: SaleDate and unique Product count;

My select looks like this:

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT sd.SaleID, sd.ProductID FROM dbo.Products p
        INNER JOIN dbo.SalesDetails sd ON sd.ProductID = p.ID
    GROUP BY sd.SaleID, sd.ProductID
)
SELECT
     c.Name AS ManagerName
    ,s.SaleDate
    ,COUNT(ct.ProductID) AS ProductCount
FROM cte ct
    INNER JOIN dbo.Sales s ON ct.SaleID = s.ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Managers c ON c.ID = s.ConsultantID
GROUP BY s.SaleDate, c.Name
```

Is this optimal? Can you help my to replace it with more optimal query

- Managers: [ID = 1, Name = John;]
- Sales: [ID = 1, ManagerID = 1, SaleNO = 0015, SaleDate: 2016-09-08], [ID = 2, ManagerID = 1, SaleNO = 0016, SaleDate: 2016-09-09]
- SaleDetails: [ID = 1, SaleID = 1, ProductID = 1, Quantity = 2], [ID =
  2, SaleID = 1, ProductID = 1, Quantity = 4], [ID = 3, SaleID = 1,
  ProductID = 2, Quantity = 3], [ID = 4, SaleID = 2,
  ProductID = 1, Quantity = 3]
- Product: [ID = 1, Name = Sony],  [ID = 2, Name = Samsung]

Query must return results:

- ManagerName = John, SaleDate = 2016-09-08, ProductCount = 2
- ManagerName = John, SaleDate = 2016-09-09, ProductCount = 1

Comment: Does your query work, and are you you asking for an alternative?  If you have indices setup properly those joins might run pretty efficiently.

Comment: yes I want to write an alternative query. this query works

Comment: @www1986 Can u post you data and expected result??

Comment: @JibinBalachandran I edited my post, you can check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT c.Name AS ManagerName
      ,s.SaleDate
      ,COUNT(p.ProductID)
FROM dbo.Products p
INNER JOIN dbo.SalesDetails sd ON sd.ProductID = p.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Sales s ON sd.SaleID = s.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Managers c ON c.ID = s.ConsultantID
GROUP BY s.SaleDate, c.Name,sd.ProductID
```

Comment: @www1986 Updated my answer,Check it now and let me know if you get any problem.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer (as I read the question) is:

```
SELECT c.Name AS ManagerName, s.SaleDate, COUNT(DISTINCT sd.ProductId)
FROM dbo.SalesDetails sd
     dbo.Sales s
     ON sd.SaleID = s.ID INNER JOIN
     dbo.Managers c
     ON c.ID = s.ConsultantID
GROUP BY s.SaleDate, c.Name;
```

Notes:

- The `Products` table is not needed, because the `SalesDetails` table has the product information.
- The product id does not go in the `GROUP BY`.
- The correct aggregation function is `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Comment: yes, you are right, but if want to filter with product price? for example where p.price > 500

Comment: @www1986 . . . That is not the question that you asked.  In that case, you would need the product table, if the information were not in `salesdetails`.